# Get value from multiple select in server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get value from multiple select

```
<select name="role" id="role" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="multiple"> 
                          <option value="">Role</option>
                          <option value="dekanat">Dekanat</option>
                          <option value="dosen_bisnis">Dosen Jurusan Bisnis</option>
                          <option value="dosen_publik">Dosen Jurusan Publik</option>
                          <option value="staff_tu">Staff Tata Usaha</option>
                          <option value="staff_bisnis">Staff Jurusan Bisnis</option>
                          <option value="staff_publik">Staff Jurusan Publik</option>
                        </select>
```

How to get the value in server side? I have tried this, but it doesnt work. It returns undefined

```
module.exports.list_email_insert_post = function(req, res) {
    var test = req.body.role;
    console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: forgive me if this doesn't help at all.... In PHP if you want to access data from a multiple select I believe you have to add [] to the element name so the data is passed as an array... `name="role[]"`

Comment: @Dale — Most programming languages don't impose that naming restriction.

Comment: You have some code which parses the data from the body of the HTTP request and presents you with whatever value `req.body` is. Normally you would use a library such as Body Parser. You haven't told us what code you are using to do that, and the answer will depend on it. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: yes i use body parser

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. How are you configuring it?

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array to get the multiple select data

```
<select name="role[]" id="role" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="multiple"> 
    <option value="">Role</option>
    <option value="dekanat">Dekanat</option>
    <option value="dosen_bisnis">Dosen Jurusan Bisnis</option>
    <option value="dosen_publik">Dosen Jurusan Publik</option>
    <option value="staff_tu">Staff Tata Usaha</option>
    <option value="staff_bisnis">Staff Jurusan Bisnis</option>
    <option value="staff_publik">Staff Jurusan Publik</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you changed anything ? Or can you please show the updated code